# How to create a rule-based gradient using an expression

Tags: qgis, point, style

I am mapping points with values from 0-100 and want to display these using a gradient color scheme. However I also want to specify the breaks as regular intervals along this range. For a gradient QGIS automatically chooses breaks but doesn't allow me to specify the start, stop, and interval size. Alternatively I can use rule-based styling but it becomes tedious to update the point sizes, colors, etc.

Is there are smarter way to get QGIS to create a gradient style but retain the flexibility of the rule-based cutoffs as well? The points share the same attributes except for color, which is determined by gradient.

Answer (score 1):

For this use case I'd suggest to specify the cutoffs by setting a respective query in **General | Feature subset** and then configure the **graduated renderer**.

Similar results could be achieved using data-defined styling if you don't mind that QGIS currently cannot create a legend for data-defined styles.